# The simplest Solr DIH indexing

Tags: solr, dih

I'm trying to index data from a database in Solr using the DIH.

So I have modified the two config files as follows:

**solrconfig.xml** :

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" 
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

**data-config.xml** :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="****"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="source_scellee" query="select * from source_scellee">
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

source_scellee being the name of my table on my test database. It contains many fields.

Obviously, I'm trying to run nothing else than a simple test. When running http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true I get the following **result** :

```
<str name="Full Dump Started">2012-01-27 12:27:01</str><str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 4 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str><str name="Committed">2012-01-27 12:27:02</str>
<str name="**Total Documents Failed**">4</str>
```

Besides no warning nor error on the server logs. 4 is my number of records inside table "source_scellee". But it says all documents fail.

If I run a query from http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/
no results appear, at all !! How can I solve it ?
("*:*" shows no results)

Thank you for your help!!!

----edit---
I have added these lines to my schema.xml :

```
<field name="ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="reference_catalogue"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="reference_capsule"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="organisme_certificateur"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="reference_certificat"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="duree_d_utilisation"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="activite_nominale"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="activite_minimale"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="activite_maximale"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="coffret"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="dispositif_medical"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="forme_speciale" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="exemption_cpa"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="marquage_ce"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="element_cible"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

However the result is still the same: no results when querying (I tried to restart solr, and to re-index all also)

------second edit---
I have tried the dynamic import
Now my **data-config.xml** looks like this :

```
<document>
       <entity name="source_scellee" query="select * from source_scellee">
            <field column="ID" name="ID_i" />
            <field column="reference_catalogue" name="reference_catalogue_s" />
            <field column="reference_capsule" name="reference_capsule_s" />
            <field column="organisme_certificateur" name="organisme_certificateur_s" />
            <field column="reference_certificat" name="reference_certificat_s" />
            <field column="duree_d_utilisation" name="duree_d_utilisation_s" />
            <field column="activite_nominale" name="activite_nominale_s" />
            <field column="activite_minimale" name="activite_minimale_s" />
            <field column="activite_maximale" name="activite_maximale_s" />
            <field column="coffret" name="coffret_b" />
            <field column="dispositif_medical" name="dispositif_medical_b" />
            <field column="forme_speciale" name="forme_speciale_b" />
            <field column="exemption_cpa" name="exemption_cpa_b" />
            <field column="marquage_ce" name="marquage_ce_b" />
            <field column="element_cible" name="element_cible_b" />
        </entity>
    </document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) You can take a look to the statistics page to see, how much docs are indexed right now:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/stats.jsp

2.) The result of your search depends on your schema.xml, because there it's defined how docs are indexed/stored, which fields are processed and how searchs are handled on query time.
Please take a look at this file or post the field definition from the schema.xml and also the schema/design from your table `source_scellee`.
Does the columns and the fields have the same name?

//Edit: This should work, if coulmname and filedname are the same:

```
<document>
       <entity name="source_scellee" 
               pk="ID"
               query="select * from source_scellee">

        </entity>
    </document>
```

> is having NULL values in data an issue ?

that depends on the destination field.

Are your running solr in an tomcat or someting like that?
Take a look in the Java EE Container output, like catalina.out or so.

Comment: it looks like your are mapping the Table Column ID to the Solr field ID_i, but there is no filed-definition for ID_i, only for ID. If the RDBMS Columnnames and Solr-Filed-Names are same, you don't need to map the fields in data-config.xml. Take a look at my edit.  By the way: is ID unique and: you don't need to store the fields, if your focus is using the fulltext-search

Comment: So, to dynamically assign a field type to my fields I should directly rename my column names with _i or _s in the RDBMS ?
ID is unique yes.

Comment: Ok I'm getting closer to the solution !
    <str name="Total Documents Processed">5</str>
I have renamed my table names directly in the RDBMS (2 fields = id + value_s).
I can see the results appear when I run query "\*:\*". However when I do full-text search looking for a key word inside one of my records in field value_s, then I don't get the result.

Comment: that depends on how you process the values of the filed. depending, if you are using an stemmer or something like this. Try to change the field type, because string does not process the fieldvalues in the way you like. Example: "A big green car" as string and you will not find the document by searching for "green". try `type="text"` or try to create your own field-type depending on the kind of values, language and so on. (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)

Comment: ...and please mark the answer as right/correct, if it was helpful. thank you!

Comment: "green" (as string or as text) in the db and "green" in the query don't match. only "\*:\*" can get me the results.

Comment: nb: type="text_general", "text" type does not exist.

Comment: right, text_general is also possible, but take a look, how text_general is defined. text_general only takes the standard tokenizer and the lowercase filter. that means, if your value is "there are green cars" and you search for "car" there is no hit, because car != cars, because text_general does not use a stemmer.

Comment: Of course, but here obviously I am not dealing with this kind of issue. I have <doc><str name="id">6</str><str name="value_t">car</str></doc> in my global results for "\*:\*". Though, if I search "car", no result will come up.

Comment: ah, if I specify my query with the fieldname like this : "value_t: car" then the result comes up, but no way I can run a search towards all the fields of a table together.

Comment: you like to search in all fields at the same time? there are different ways: 1.) if you run a query, us the  "query - Field" parameter to define the field where you like to search in or 2.) use copy filed in schema.xml to bring all the content of all fields to one field

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the issue lies in how the DIH is trying to map fields. Thanks for adding the information from your schema file... However, I believe that what you have done is added configuration that needs to be added separately to both the schema.xml and the data-config.xml for the DIH.

Based on the [Full Import Example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example) from the Solr Wiki, I would try the following.

**schema.xml**

```
 <field name="ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="reference_catalogue"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="reference_capsule"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="date_de_creation"  type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="organisme_certificateur"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="reference_certificat"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="duree_d_utilisation"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="activite_nominale"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="activite_minimale"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="activite_maximale"   type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="coffret"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="dispositif_medical"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="forme_speciale" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="exemption_cpa"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="marquage_ce"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="element_cible"  type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**data-config.xml**

```
 <dataConfig>
     <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="****"/>
     <document>
         <entity name="source_scellee" query="select * from source_scellee">
           <field column="ID" name="ID"/>
           <field column="reference_catalogue" name="reference_catalogue"/>
           <field column="reference_capsule" name="reference_capsule"/>
           <field column="date_de_creation" name="date_de_creation"/>
           <field column="organisme_certificateur" name="organisme_certificateur"/>
           <field column="reference_certificat" name="reference_certificat"/>
           <field column="duree_d_utilisation" name="duree_d_utilisation"/>
           <field column="activite_nominale" name="activite_nominale"/>
           <field column="activite_minimale" name="activite_minimale"/>
           <field column="activite_maximale" name="activite_maximale"/>
           <field column="coffret" name="coffret"/>
           <field column="dispositif_medical" name="dispositif_medical"/>
           <field column="forme_speciale" name="forme_speciale"/>
           <field column="exemption_cpa" name="exemption_cpa"/>
           <field column="marquage_ce" name="marquage_ce"/>
           <field column="element_cible" name="element_cible"/>
         </entity>
     </document>
 </dataConfig>
```

There is a way to setup the schema.xml to dynamically add fields that it encounters by using some naming conventions. Please see the [Dynamic Fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) details in the Solr Wiki for more details and some examples of how this can be done.

Comment: Yes, I'm struggling with this mapping between schema.xml and data-config.xml... but still can't make it work :S
I have tried this above solution too, also even have tried to remove some fields from my database =D
I will rename my table fields with suffixes to be able to try the dynamic fields feature, I keep you posted.
Thx

Comment: What if you keep it simple and only try to select and index the first two columns from your table, ID and reference-catalogue, (or just the ID and a simple string field) by only defining those two fields to the data-config.xml file? As the issue could be in your data and you may need to use a transformer - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Transformer to massage the data going into the solr fields.

Comment: is having NULL values in data an issue ?

Comment: It should not be, but you might want to try excluding them until you can get things indexing properly and then add them back in.

Comment: a short table with two fields and no NULL values in the records does not make it work either anyway :(

Comment: Last thing I can think of is to try debugging your DIH request using either the `debug=on` parameter or via the interface at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/dataimport.jsp These should give you some more insight into what is happening and hopefully help you solve the issue.

Comment: Ever happened to you ? I have <doc><str name="id">6</str><str name="value_t">car</str></doc> in my global results for "\*:\*". Though, if I search "car", no result will come up. Results only come up when searching with the stars.

Comment: ah, if I specify my query with the fieldname like this : "value_t: car" then the result comes up, but no way I can run a search towards all the fields of a table together.